# Как CLR проверяет корни и объекты, на которые они (корни) ссылаются?

Tags: c#, .net, память, сборщик-мусора, clr

Рихтер Дж. CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 на языке C#. 4-е изд., стр. 557:

> Когда среда CLR запускает уборку мусора, она сначала приостанавливает все программные потоки в процессе. Тем самым предотвращается обращение к объектам и возможное изменение состояния во время их анализа CLR. Затем CLR переходит к этапу уборки мусора, называемому маркировкой (marking). CLR перебирает все объекты в куче, задавая биту в поле индекса блока синхронизации значение 0. Это означает, что все эти объекты могут быть удалены. Затем CLR проверяет все активные корни и объекты, на которые они ссылаются. Если корень содержит null, CLR игнорирует его и переходит к следующему корню.

1. Для начала, "кто такие" ***активные** корни*? Или, все же идет речь о проверке **всех** корней процесса?
2. Но сбил меня с толку вот этот кусок: ***...CLR проверяет все  активные
   корни и объекты, на которые они ссылаются. Если корень содержит
   null***.... Я думал, что этот процесс выглядит чуть-чуть наоборот: У CLR
   есть некий список

[image: объекты процесса в управляемой кучи]

где он проверяет все объекты - доступны ли далее в стеке вызовов все корни ссылающееся на него (объект) и если таких корней нет, то идет дальше, не маркируя объект.

**Мы сейчас с Рихтером говорим об одном и том же, или?**

Comment: @VladD, таблица, как я уже сказал, это мое понимание как CLR хранит информацию о том какие поля/переменные ссылаются на определенный объект.

Comment: @VladD, под _трассировкой_ в данном контексте вы понимаете _обход_ корней на наличие null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

*Корнями*, насколько я понимаю, называются корневые объекты, объекты, которые точно не нужно убирать. Это статические объекты, а также объекты, ссылки на которых есть в стеке.

Затем, у CLR нет таблиц того, кто ссылается на данный объект. Поддерживать такие таблицы в порядке было бы неоправданно дорого. Вместо этого, для каждого объекта CLR знает его тип, а значит, знает, где в нём лежат ссылки, то есть, знает, на какие объекты он ссылается. Поэтому CLR видит объекты как граф со ссылками, и обходит ссылки, начиная от корней, используя стандартный поиск (в глубину или там в ширину, не так уж важно).

Вот этот самый обход и называется трассировкой.

---

Заметьте, что на текущий момент уборка мусора сложнее, чем описание, которое вы приводите. Объекты делятся на *поколения*, и сборка происходит параллельно работе программы, в фоне.

Comment: _а также объекты, ссылки на которых есть в стеке_ разве не `все` ссылки хранятся в стеке?

Comment: @adamshakhabov: Нет, не все. Вот к примеру, у вас есть объект в куче, и он ссылается на другой объект. Эта самая ссылка на другой объект находится не в стеке.

Comment: ```сборка происходит параллельно работе программы, в фоне``` разве всегда так? Вроде есть случаи, когда при сборке стопится всё на свете :)

Comment: @tym32167: Ну, если быть совсем точным, то остановки есть, но они маленькие: http://mattwarren.org/2014/06/18/measuring-the-impact-of-the-net-garbage-collector/

Comment: Спасибо за статью. Не знал, что для джавы уже есть GC который не стопит ничего.

Comment: @tym32167: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, для .NET кто-нибудь тоже напишет.