# Нюансы работы сборщика мусора

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Подскажите, как сборщик мусора "узнает" что ссылок на объект уже нет, объект класса перестает использоваться и он удаляется?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710700/10105

Comment: @VladD, почему не бахнул?

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за инфу и что не бахнул!

Comment: @VladD, ответа на мой вопрос в данном топике не обнаружилось.

Comment: @OlegLarionov: Да есть же вроде. Корневые объекты, а также все объекты, достижимые от корневых, маркируются. Все немаркированные объекты недостижимы, и их-то сборщик мусора и убирает.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за уточнение.