# Сборка муссора в C#

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

изучаю сборку мусора в C#. Узнал что сборка происходит в три этапа

- Маркировка
- Сборка
- Сжатие

Перед маркировкой строится граф ссылок где корнем может быть локальные переменные, статические. Все объекты которые входят в этот граф помечаются как используемые и они не подвергаются сборке мусора. Так же можно выделить понятие как активные и не активные корни.

**Активные корни** - это объекты на которые есть ссылки к примеру от статических переменных, локальных.

 **Не активные корни** - (обновленно) такого понятия не может быть.

**Так вот мне интересно уничтожаются ли не активные корни?** Или может уничтожаются но не все, к примеру локальные прееменные да, а статические нет. **Правильно ли я все расписал (я упустил специально некоторые подробности такие как поколения дабы не перегружать вопрос) ?** 

 
Что к примеру произойдет с ссылкой **A**?
Если бы к примеру на объект **D** не было ссылки, он бы считался недостижимым обектом и был бы удален, но он не корень.

Вот здесь поднималась похожая тема [Как CLR проверяет корни и объекты, на которые они (корни) ссылаются?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710700/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-clr-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F?rq=1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "это ссылки на объекты которые ни на кого не ссылаются" похоже скорее на нулевые ссылки. Вам бы стоили привести пример.

Comment: Похоже немного не правильно выразился, сейчас исправлю. Походу все наоборот,  это ссылка которую используют другие объекты

Comment: `Активные корни - это ссылки на объекты которые используются объектом.` если мне память не изменяет, то корни - это что то другое. Я представлял, что корни - они всегда в стеке. То есть те переменные, что в стеке, могут быть корнями.

Comment: ну все верно, я тоже так думаю, корень это ссылка которая находится в стеке

Comment: В таком случае, корень, по определению, не может быть уничтожен, разые нет? Вот когда он перестанет быть корнем, тогда да

Comment: Корень не может перестать быть корнем, на сколько я знаю. Вы же не можете статик переменную в рантайме переделать

Comment: статик переменную нет, а вот локальная переменная на стеке когда-нибудь будет убрана из стека и перестанет быть корнем

Comment: на сколько я знаю, локальная будет удалена в конце метода, она не то что корнем не будет, ее вообще не будет

Comment: ну а пока она не удалена из стека, она является корнем. Сборка мусора же может начаться и в середине выполнения какого то метода, то есть метод ещё не кончился, локальные переменные в стеке, и они являются корнями, которые будут уничтожены только после того, как метод кончится, переменные будут выкинуты из стека и корнями быть перестанут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корни — это объекты, с которых начинает строиться граф объектов.

Корни могут быть только активными, потому что сборщик мусора не строит графы неактивных объектов. Те, что в конце оказались непомеченными, те и есть неактивные.

Рассмотрим пример со статическим свойством.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public static Bar Bar { get; set; } = new Bar();
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }

    public string Qux { get; set; }
    . . .
}
```

Здесь `Foo.Bar` — статическое свойство, в котором хранится ссылка на объект `Bar`, где находятся строки `Baz` и `Qux`.

При сборке мусора `Foo.Bar` это активный корень, и все объекты, доступные из него, будут считаться используемыми.

Обнулим свойство:

```cs
Foo.Bar = null;
```

У нас в памяти остались объект `Bar`, и строки `Baz` и `Qux`. Но теперь на них нет ссылок ниоткуда. Когда сборщик мусора в следующий раз будет строить граф используемых объектов, он их не найдёт и не пометит.

Поэтому сборщик очистит память, которую занимают все три объекта. Важно помнить, что адрес объекта `Bar` в этот момент не хранится ни в статическом поле, ни в локальной переменной. И — по определению — он уже не корень.

Comment: хорошо а к примеру если бы Foo.Bar = new Bar() но поля внутри Baz и Qux равны null. Тогда бы new Bar() был бы утилизирован? Я так полагаю нет, потому что он в статик переменную записан

Comment: @Snuppi Если в свойстве `Foo.Bar` хранится адрес объекта `Bar`, то он не будет утилизирован. Как только присвоите `null`, объект станет недоступен и будет освобождён при следующей чистке мусора.

Comment: Кажется все понял, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Имхо, нет такого понятия, как "неактивные корни" так как корень у приложения один. Правильнее говорить "недостижимые объекты из корня приложения."

Статика не очищается. Очистка статики происходит лишь при выгрузке домена.

Ресурсы системы тоже автоматически не вычитаются => если взяли какой-то дескриптор у системы через WinAPI, то вы должны его вернуть. В противном случае утечка ресурсов.

Так же очистке локальных переменных препятствует конструкция fixed, которая заставляет сборщик мусора обруливать эти участки, так как там идет прямая работа с указателями под ответственностью программиста.

Comment: Вы не поняли, под корнем я имел ввиду корень графа ссылок с которого начинается обход графа. Недостежимые ссылки - это ссылки которые не вошли в этот граф, ссылки (на объекты) на которые не кто не ссылается т.е их нет в графе. Не путайтет недостежимые сслыки и неактивные корни. Недостежимые сслыки - подвергаются сборке мусора

Comment: Я это понял. Однако, термин не совсем корректен. В литературе про это пишут, как "недостижимые объекты".

Comment: Хм я просто недавно читал и встречал такой термин и ни раз. Все же должна же быть какая-то разница между корнем графа объектов и листом этого графа. Я подкоректировал свой вопрос с примерами, возможно, теперь немного понятнее. Спасибо за ответы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710700/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-clr-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F?rq=1 вот похожая тема здесь поднималась